# correct way to handle select + insert to avoid duplicates errors

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Hello I have a simple MySQL InnoDB table with only two fields:

- id   - autoincrement primary index
- name - unique index

I am importing some data from various sources in parallel and I need to make sure that the data is not duplicated at insert so I am doing the following:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `name` = <name>;
 if `id` <= 0
  INSERT INTO `table` SET `name` = "<name>";
  return AUTO_INCREMENT
 else return `id`
```

This works 99.9999% of the times but it can happen (and has happened to me) that two or more different scripts are inserting the same data because both SELECT returned `id` <=0 so both do an INSERT and one of them raises an error.

I have two possible solutions in mind but I am not sure what would work best.

One more piece of information: initially the import will NOT find the elements in the table but as more of the elements are inserted the probability to be found grows.  The final table, after some rough calculation, will have approximately 7-10 Million records :

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `name` = <name>;
if `id` <= 0
 INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` SET `name` = "<name>";
 get AUTO_INCREMENT
  if AUTO_INCREMENT <=0
   SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `name` = <name>;
   return `id`
  else return AUTO_INCREMENT
else return `id`
```

OR

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` SET `name` = "<name>";
get AUTO_INCREMENT
 if AUTO_INCREMENT <=0
  SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `name` = <name>;
  return `id`
 else return AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: You have said your requirement is to avoid duplicating data upon insert, in a two column table `(id,name)`.  What's a duplicate in this case? two `name` values that are the same?

Comment: yes, the insert are jut on unique `name` two scripts trying to insert the same data at the same time because also the select was performed at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting a race condition. When your code detects that a new insertion is necessary, then two of your clients are racing to be the first to insert that value. It's winner-take-all.  You need to write your code to avoid this race condition. Fortunately, SQL is specifically designed so it's possible to do that.

You have a couple of choices here, both specific to MySQL's dialect of SQL.

One is to use the built-in function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. It serves the purpose I believe you mean by `get AUTO_INCREMENT`.

The other is to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

It looks like your logic is intended to do two things:

1. make sure the `name` value is in the table, putting it there if it isn't already.
2. return the `id` value associated with the name value.

You can do this like so.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (name) VALUES (<name>);
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE name = <name>;
```

Notice that the `INSERT IGNORE` operation doesn't get caught by race conditions between different programs hitting the database, because it's a single SQL statement.

You can, possibly, optimize this by using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (name) VALUES (<name>);
if (LAST_INSERT_ID()=0) then do the select.
```

Comment: yes, I was using pseudocode.  I am using `last_insert_id` but the problem happens when two different scripts running at the same time do the `select` at the same time and both get 0, so they both try to `insert` causing the second script to error out.

Comment: @Fabrizio . . . I think `insert on duplicate key update` should fix that problem.

Comment: @gordon, the "on duplicate keys update" does not return a key if there is not an insert happening, meaning I will have to do a select after

Comment: @ollie I understand the solution, but the problem is that as the table get filled the inserts will fail more and more often... do you believe that big imports where network traffic is as important as the ability to select from the table as fast as possible are handled like that or is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: @Fabrizio . . . The index check on unique takes about the same amount of time whether the value is found or not.  There may be a bit more overhead in unwinding a transaction rather than completing it.  But as for your performance concerns, they depend on your application requirements.